# Trying to post date via php with mySQL... Need help

Tags: php, mysql, date, post

I'm trying to post the date and time at the time I create a new record.  The record is created but the 'add_time' column is blank in mySQL.

What's wrong with it?

```
$date = date("Y-m-d G:i:s") ; 

$order = "INSERT INTO cartons_added (add_time, type, part_no, add_type, add_qty, 
add_ref, add_by, add_notes)

VALUES
('$_POST[date]',
 '$_POST[type]', 
 '$_POST[part_no]', 
 '$_POST[add_type]', 
 '$_POST[add_qty]', 
 '$_POST[add_ref]', 
 '$_POST[add_by]', 
 '$_POST[add_notes]')";

 $result = mysql_query($order);
```

Comment: Depends on what type the `add_time` column is and what `$_POST[date]` contains. Also, your script is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)

Comment: It's a very bad idea to simply use `$_POST` data inside a query. Consider using [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or at least [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe instead of:

```
VALUES
('$_POST[date]',
 '$_POST[type]', 
 '$_POST[part_no]', 
 '$_POST[add_type]', 
 '$_POST[add_qty]', 
 '$_POST[add_ref]', 
 '$_POST[add_by]', 
 '$_POST[add_notes]')";
```

You mean to use

```
// Use your $date variable

VALUES
('$date',
 '$_POST[type]', 
 '$_POST[part_no]', 
 '$_POST[add_type]', 
 '$_POST[add_qty]', 
 '$_POST[add_ref]', 
 '$_POST[add_by]', 
 '$_POST[add_notes]')";
```

All of this needs a great deal of treatment for protection against SQL injection.  The easiest path to take is to surround all `$_POST` vars in `mysql_real_escape_string()`:

```
"...
VALUES
('$date',
 '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['type']) ."', 
 '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['part_no']) ."', 
 '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['add_type']) ."', 
 '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['add_qty']) ."', 
 '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['add_ref']) ."', 
 '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['add_by']) ."', 
 '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['add_notes']) ."')";
```

Comment: -1, with 23k rep you cannot leave that big SQL-injection hole open. That's just negligent. Also, you have a syntax error in your code, so it will not even work.

Comment: @Micheal, I suggest you keep editing, because the syntax errors are still there.

Comment: @Johan, where are the syntax errors please? And I hope you are not calling `$_POST[param]` vs. `$_POST['param']` a *syntax error*.

Comment: @MajidFouladpour, that is the issue I'm referring to. What would you call it then?

Comment: To be really strict, that could be described as a bad practice (yet syntactically 100% correct).

Comment: @MajidFouladpour, I just tested it and it works, `'$_POST[name]'` seems to be equivalent to `$_POST['name']` Thanks for enlightening me there.

Comment: @Johan Actually pretty surprised that notation doesn't throw strict warnings.

Comment: The worst scenario is when you have a constant named `param` with the value of `foo`, then `$_POST[param]` would effectively be `$_POST['foo']`; but if you don't (which will be 99.99% of cases, PHP decides you meant `'param'` as there is no `param` constant, and would issue a `E_NOTICE`.

Answer (score 2):

You're never using the `$date` variable you created. You probably meant to use that instead of `$_POST[date]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to fix that SQL-injection hole:
<strike>There's also a syntax error, it's not `$_POST[add_ref]`, but `$_POST['add_ref']`</strike>
*You can write `'$_POST[name]'` **(bad)** instead of `$_POST['name']`, **(good)** but don't it's bad practice.*

Change the code to:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO cartons_added (add_time, type, part_no, add_type, add_qty, 
                                     add_ref, add_by, add_notes)
    VALUES
    ('$date',
     '{mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['type'])}', 
     '{mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['part_no'])}', 
     '{mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['add_type'])}', 
     '{mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['add_qty'])}', 
     '{mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['add_ref'])}', 
     '{mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['add_by'])}', 
     '{mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['add_notes'])}') ";
```

Never ever ever insert a `$_POST`, `$_GET`, `$_SESSION` and alike stuff directly into a query.
See: [How does the SQL injection from the "Bobby Tables" XKCD comic work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/xkcd-sql-injection-please-explain)

Comment: It's sort of implied that SQL injection protection is used. Please don't -1 everyone for not having the correct answer - a simple comment is enough, unless you're disturbingly elitist.

Comment: SQL-injection protection is not elitist, it essential and if people post answers with `$_POST['injectmehere']` directly into a query then that doesn't imply anything other than complete disregard for basic protection.

Comment: And besides the downvotes where for SQL-injection **and** syntax errors. The two answers involved (one of which you rightfully deleted) will not even run!

Comment: I never said SQL injection protection is elitist, only your downvoting of everything unnecessarily in my opinion.

Comment: @JamWaffles I gave a -1 for an answer that has syntax errors and will not work for that reason. Please explain how an answer that does not work, will never work and has SQL-injection issues as a cherry on top does not deserve a downvote.